# Claim duty back on phone purchased via contract termination because moving overseas

Tags: australia, travel, gst, mobile-phone-plans, immigration

6 months ago I signed up for a 24 month phone plan which  included a phone at no additional cost. Today I am preparing to move from Australia to the  UK for a new job and I will have to cancel my phone contract. The phone plan has no early termination fee but I do have to pay for the proportional cost of the phone which I will be taking overseas with me.  I didn't sign the contract with the intent of paying it out to take the phone overseas but it will be spending the majority of its functional life in another country.

Years ago I purchased a camera for taking  holiday photos while on a tourist trip. In that case, I was able to claim the duty (tax) back at the counters after departure. I wonder if the same applies to the phone?

The same holds true for my wife's phone. It's also a 24 month contract and I think she is now 12 or 18 months into it. Does that change things?

Comment: Wait - you're from Aus?  (Mate?!)  I don't think you can claim anything at all, leaving Aus, if you are an Aus.